# How Magento2 creates object of factory classes

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, object-manager

I would like to know how magento is using factory class to create an object i.e, when we use `$classFactory->create()` function then it return object of the class.

**How from which set of code does this whole process is taking place.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**By Default create() and get() method is responsible for generate new object and retrieve obejct in magento 2.**

Both function are defined in **vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php**

When you open above file, You can check create and get function defination.
with `__construct()` defined in above file,

```
public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory, ConfigInterface $config, &$sharedInstances = [])
{
    $this->_config = $config;
    $this->_factory = $factory;
    $this->_sharedInstances = &$sharedInstances;
    $this->_sharedInstances['Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface'] = $this;
}
```

Here, **$this->_factory** is responsible for calling below files,
`Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\FactoryInterface` is used to create dynamic object in magento 2.

```
Where FactoryInterface is linked to Magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer class.
```

**So all logic are resides in below files of create and get factory object,**

**All Dynamic Object are created from below path,**

For **Developer mode** Object Creation is processed from this file,

```
vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php
```

For **Production mode** Object Creation is processed from this file,

```
vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Production.php
```

Above **both file extends** `Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php` file.

**create() function is responsible for create dynamic object of perticular factory.**

Comment: Can you explain little bit more as in magento 1 it was very clear when we were using getsingelton and getmodel, they were called using mage. So I was easily able to understand those function and autoload was responsible for figuring out the path. But Magento2 has confused me, i wanted to explore how it is reaching over here(object manager) from constructor. I hope you understand my query. You can share some link if you know regarding this.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Nice explanation Rakesh :)

Answer (score 1):

Though Rakesh has already given a good explanation. I would like to add my research. I wanted to know how constructor parameter object are created, how factory pattern is working for that:-

`$this->_factory` in create function of **Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager** class is an object of **Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer** class. 
In Developer.php we have create function which is getting the constructor parameter using line

```
$parameters = $this->definitions->getParameters($type);
```

In class **Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime** we have a
function **getParameters** function which is fetching parameters of constructor.

```
public function getParameters($className)
{
    if (!array_key_exists($className, $this->_definitions)) {
        $this->_definitions[$className] = $this->_reader->getConstructor($className);
    }
    return $this->_definitions[$className];
}
```

So from here I understand that parameter are being fetched and for object creation:-

In class **Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer**, we have return statement as `return $this->createObject($type, $args);`.
Here

```
$type = classname
$args = list of partameters
```

Now `$this->createObject` is an instance of **Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory**

And here it can be clearly seen that objects are created in function

```
createObject($type, $args)
{
    return new $type(...array_values($args));
}
```

To know more for Request flow of magento 2 you can go through this [link](http://www.w3solver.com/magento2-request-flow/)